# How to trigger Local notifications in android based on values stored in DB?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am a school student fresh for android programming. I am daily updating myself in programming and now i am doing a small demo project.
I want to show local notifications to users on particular date and time saved in DB. I have searched a lot of tutorials but i cant understand how to do it since i am new to this.

I have used Sqlite Db and successfully saved all data's like date and time.
As of my understanding,

**Get value from db (Date and time)
 Compare with today's date and time. If both equals trigger a notification.**

But how to check for each second for specified time in DB?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a background service that gets the date and time entries from your database and the current date and time of your device, and then match them.
You can use this code or you can search for AsyncTask as well.

```
public class MatchTime extends Service {

Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdates);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdates, 1000); // 1 second
    return START_STICKY;
}

private Runnable sendUpdates = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        matchTime();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 50000); // 5 second notifier
    }
};

public void matchTime() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer bro.  Inside matchTime() method, i got date and time from DB and today's timestamp and compared it. I also registered service in Manifest. Now should i use AlarmManager to trigger notification bro?

Comment: yes, put the condition in matchTime() function that if time matches, then use NotificationManager(search  about it) and you can generate notifications. Hope it helps